# Выбрать все даты с максимальным временем

Tags: sql, postgresql, laravel

Добрый день.

Есть таблица c полем created_at.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо выбрать все даты с максимальным временем в каждых сутках.

Из данного примерно должно получиться:

> 2018-01-25 06:00:04
>
> 2018-01-24 23:00:04

Проект на Laravel 5.5 база данных PostgreSQL 10.1

Подскажите как можно решить данную задачу?

Comment: По идее направление решения следующее. Сначала потренируйтесь отрезать от даты время и делать `GROUP BY` дат, потом уже на каждую дату делать выборку MAX() даты.

Comment: Блин вы просто мой герой ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена. Спасибо АК.

```
SELECT max(created_at::TIMESTAMP) as date FROM statistics WHERE channel_id = 2 GROUP BY created_at::DATE ORDER BY date DESC
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]